# HTML table for each date in multiple date range

Tags: php, sql

I currently have a table that stores a few events, it looks like that :

```
+----+---------+------------+
| ID |   Name  |    date    |
+----+---------+------------+
|  1 | Event1  | 2018-10-01 |
|  2 | Event2  | 2014-10-01 |
|  3 | Event3  | 2014-10-04 |
+----+---------+------------+
```

Then, I display it in multiple HTML table for each date :

```
$current_date = null;


while ($donnees = $reponse->fetch()) {
   $date = $formatter->format(date_create($donnees['date'])); //I translate the dateformat in french

   if ($date != $current_date) {
      $current_date = $date;
      echo "<table class='table table-menu'>";
      echo "<thead class='thead-light'><tr><th>{$current_date}</th></tr></thead>";
      echo "<tbody>";
   }

   echo "<tr><td>" . $donnees["name"] . "</td></tr>";
}
echo "</tbody></table>";
```

And it displays this (which is what I expected) :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hG7MU.jpg (I'm sorry the date is in french format)

Now, I'd like to evolve my table so that some events can take place on several days :

```
+----+---------+----------------+--------------+
| ID |   Name  |   date_start   |   date_end   |
+----+---------+----------------+--------------+
|  1 | Event1  |   2018-10-01   |  2018-10-01  |
|  2 | Event2  |   2014-10-01   |  2018-10-05  |
|  3 | Event3  |   2014-10-03   |  2018-10-05  |
+----+---------+----------------+--------------+
```

The objective is to get more or less the same kind of HTML table as before, like that : https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZPBK.jpg

If you want a real exemple, you can check this website : https://vide-greniers.org/01-Ain?_otid=home-list
It shows a lot of garage sales anywhere in France, and I'm trying to do the same for events in small cities !

A potential solution would be a calendar table, but I don't know how it works, and, if possible, I'd like to work on only one table (it sounds easier...)

Thanks a lot for your time ! :)

Comment: you can do something like , by looping through date-start, and then nested loop date_end; and check if event exists in date range add event on date_start

Comment: I am assuming the ID column is a mistake and you do not have two Id items of the same number. You want an event hit for each day between start and end to appear on the calendar?

Answer (score 0):

I think you simply need to change the logic of your `if` statement.

```
$current_date = date("Y-m-d");
while ($donnees = $reponse->fetch()) {
   $date_start = date_create($donnees['date_start']))
   $date_end = date_create($donnees['date_end']);
   if ($date_start <= $current_date && $date_end >= $current_date) { 
      echo "<table class='table table-menu'>";       
      echo "<thead class='thead-light'><tr><th>";
      echo  $formatter->format($current_date);
      echo "</th></tr></thead><tbody>";
   }
   echo "<tr><td>" . $donnees["name"] . "</td></tr>";
   echo "</tbody></table>";
   $current_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("$current_date +1 day"));
}
```

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for the reply. I understand the idea, I tried it with an example. $current_date only iterates once, and the "if" is executed only once too

Comment: @Hara I think I see whats happening. I suspect you need to create a loop on the days to check and not the items in the DB. Will update it.

Comment: @Twitsy Should it be something like "while ($date_start <= $current_date && $date_end >= $current_date) { 
// Iterates $current_date
}" ?